# how to pass data to child component with <input> tag and v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

i am trying to pass value from a parent component to a child component as shown in the code posted below. the property in the child component that will receive a value passed from the parent component is bound to `v-model` as shown below in the code.

```
<input :value="refInputModel"
         @input="refInputModel = $event.target.value"/>
</div>
```

what i expected at the run time of the posed code, is when the button `counterFunc` is clicked, then the value `changed` as in the following line:

```
refInputModel.value = "changed"
```

will be passed to the child component as set on the `<input>`, but that does not happen

please let me know how to pass values from parent to `<input>` tag with `v-model` in child component

**App**

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">

  <div>
  <button @click="counterFunc">methodHandler</button>
  <hello-world :refInputModel='refInputModel'/>
  
</div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup> 
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import {ref,defineProps} from 'vue' 

const props = defineProps(['inputModel_'])
let refInputModel = ref(props.inputModel_)

const counterFunc = ()=> {
  refInputModel.value = "changed"
}
</script>
```

**HelloWorld**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
  <input :value="refInputModel"
         @input="refInputModel = $event.target.value"/>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
}
</script>

<script setup> 
import { defineProps, ref} from 'vue'

const props= defineProps(['inputModel'])
let refInputModel = ref(props.inputModel)

onUpdated(()=>{
    console.log("HelloWorld.onUpdated");
    console.log("refInputModel:",refInputModel.value);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) link, and as stated in it:

```
`v-model` can be used on a component to implement a two-way binding.
```

for the follwoing example:

```
<input v-model="searchText" />
```

it is equivalent to:

```
<input
  :value="searchText"
  @input="searchText = $event.target.value"
/>
```

where `:value` is used to denote and specify the property name on which the binding occurs in a such way that, if `searchText` is set to any value, hence that value will be displayed in the input field
`@input` is used to denote and specify the property name on which the binding occurs in a such way that, if any value entered on the input field, that value will be assigned to `searchText` and can be retrieved via `$event.target.value`

for the exampel in the code provided below:
the child component `HelloWorld` has `input` tag and a property `modelValue`. since the `input` tag needs two-way data binding, it is necessary to dissect the `v-model` into `:value` and `@input` as shown in the code below.

on the parent component's side, the binding on input tag of the child component can occure in either of the following ways:

1- as stated in the code below

```
<hello-world :modelValue='refInputModel'
@update:modelValue="newValue => refInputModel = newValue"/>
```

or 2-

```
<hello-world v-model="refInputModel"/>
```

**App**

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">

  <div>
  <button @click="counterFunc">methodHandler</button>
  <hello-world :modelValue='refInputModel'
                @update:modelValue="newValue => refInputModel = newValue"/>
  
</div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup> 
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import {ref,defineProps} from 'vue' 

const props = defineProps(['inputModel_'])
let refInputModel = ref(props.inputModel_)

const counterFunc = ()=> {
  refInputModel.value = "changed"
}
</script>
```

**HelloWorld**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
  <input :value="modelValue"
     @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"/>
</div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
}
</script>

<script setup> 
import { defineProps, ref} from 'vue'

defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

onUpdated(()=>{
  console.log("HelloWorld.onUpdated");
  console.log("modelValue:",props.modelValue);
})
</script>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What did you change and why? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76413667/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen i modified my answer